# Can I use seperate cloud storage and connect it to mapbox?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage, mapbox

I want to build a web service using mapbox and leaflet. There are lots of images to upload having more than 1 GB volume.
Is there any way that I could upload my data on some cloud storage and then connect it with mapbox?